# I can not open my Android SDK Manager

Tags: android

When i start my Android SDK Manager it throws this error

```
[SDK Manager] 'D:\PhanMem\PH9D61~1\Android\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

[SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
```

I use Windows 7 23 bit, i can not open my SDK so i don't know which version . How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Windows system, use following way to set your `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` Environment variables.

Windows XP

> Select Start, select Control Panel. double click System, and select
>   the Advanced tab. Click Environment Variables. In the section System
>   Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click
>   Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New. In
>   the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the
>   value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining
>   windows by clicking OK.

Windows Vista:

> From the desktop, right click the My Computer icon. Choose Properties
>   from the context menu. Click the Advanced tab (Advanced system
>   settings link in Vista). Click Environment Variables. In the section
>   System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it.
>   Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click
>   New. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window,
>   specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close
>   all remaining windows by clicking OK.

Windows 7

> From the desktop, right click the Computer icon. Choose Properties
>   from the context menu. Click the Advanced system settings link. Click
>   Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH
>   environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH
>   environment variable does not exist, click New. In the Edit System
>   Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the
>   PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by
>   clicking OK.

Now in Addition for the Linux Based System following steps used to set
JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH variables:

> Open root folder From the View Menu , ticK "Show Hidden Files" , or
>   press Ctrl + H. Now you can see a system hidden file called .bashrc
>   Right click and open it editor, and write following command at the
>   end.

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.6.0_21/bin 
export PATH
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_21
export JAVA_HOME
NDK_HOME=/opt/android-ndk-r8
export NDK_HOME
```

Save and Exit.

Comment: i use windows 7, could you explant clearly about edit PATH Environment, what will be added to current PATH, my android sdk PATH here : D:\PhanMem\PhanMemHOC TAP\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk

Answer (score 0):

find your Android sdk path, mine is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk   ... you can find yours by going into eclipse --->Window-->Android    ... the SDK location will be near the top assuming you have Android ADT installed already.

so go to your SDK path and in there you will find SDK Manager.exe , just double click it to open it.

Comment: It do not open, it just blink.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by saying which OS you are using ? And which version of the SDK you are using ?

For Windows, SDK Manager in the latest version (with eclipse) on should be in x\sdk\tools\lib\SDK Manager.exe